# Bootstrap 3 tabs preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build what seems to be simple jquery script. Once form input has been changed and user wants to leave page without saving, he will be prompted to confirm leaving. Everything works ok on regular anchors, but I can't get event.preventDefault working on Bootstrap 3 tabs. Any ideas? Thank you.

My current (beta) script:

```
//Confirm on exit when form has changed
    var show_exit_error = 1;
    $("form.check-on-exit").one("change", ":input", function() {
        show_exit_error = 1;
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
            if (show_exit_error == 1) {
                $link = $(this);
                e.preventDefault();
                swal({
                    title: "Do you really want to leave?",
                    text: "",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    cancelButtonText: "Leave",
                    confirmButtonColor: "#18a689",
                    confirmButtonText: "No",
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnCancel: true,
                }, function(isConfirm){
                    if(!isConfirm) {
                        show_exit_error = 0;
                        window.location = $link.attr('href');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdzyRy?editors=101
Try to edit one of inputs and then switch to tab2. It ignores prevetndefault and switch tab. I need script to switch tab only if user click on No.

**Here is simple workaround:**

```
//Confirm on exit when form has changed
var show_exit_error = 1;
$("form.check-on-exit").one("change", ":input", function() {
    show_exit_error = 1;
    $('.tabs-container').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('data-toggle', 'notab');
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        if (show_exit_error == 1) {
            $link = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Do you really want to leave?",
                text: "",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: "Leave",
                confirmButtonColor: "#18a689",
                confirmButtonText: "No",
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnCancel: true,
            }, function(isConfirm){
                if(!isConfirm) {
                    show_exit_error = 0;
                    if ($link.attr('data-toggle') == 'notab') {
                    $('.tabs-container').find('a[data-toggle="notab"]').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
                        $link.trigger('click');
                    } else { 
                        window.location = $link.attr('href');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bootstrap Tab Plugin calls [`e.preventDefault()`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tab.js#L147). Maybe it's possible to remove the Bootstrap Click Handler and replace it by a fixed non-default-preventing Click Handler? If the anchor points to a different document it should last to remove the click handler without replacing it, since the document will be leaved nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you for reply. There is no problem with links pointing to external documents. I added demo.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the tabs you're referring to are anchors to external documents. Since you leave the page at that moment, it would last to remove the Bootstrap click handler completely.

```
$(function() {
    // remove the click.bs.tab.data-api handler from all tabs with class .external-tabs
    $('.external-tabs').off('click.bs.tab.data-api');
});
```

As an alternate solution you could just remove the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute from the item, since this is the selector for adding the handler in Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for comment, please look at the first post, I added demo and some more explanation. But you gave me an idea to remove all datas when form has been changed, then add them if user click no and trigger click. Ill try it this way.

Comment: It worked :) Thank you, I have added modified script.